# How can I have DropDownList in each and every cell of the GridView when the headers of the GridView are Unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView`, and The headers of the `GridView` changes every time I run my program. I want `DropDownList` in each and every cell of my `GridView` as shown in the attached image.

According to the image: 
The values in the `DropDownList` under each header are = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.

Suppose I select value 2 from the `DropDownList` for KITCHEN2, When I hit on SAVE, I want 2 Lamps(Lamp1, Lamp2)(provided I have selected Lamp_profile in the first column of my GridView) to be updated in the database for Kitchen2. Similarly I want this event to happen at once for all the values that I have selected in `GridView` when I hit SAVE.

Therefore my `Gridview` is just a way to provide input, not bound to any datasource.

How do I achieve it. Any help would be useful. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand, that you don't want to bind with any datasource.  But to generate GridView output, you have to bind with datasource.  You can bind a temporary DataTable created in code. with the number of rows you want with null values.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try with TemplateField 

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
         </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kitchen1">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="Kitchen1_DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kitchen2">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="Kitchen2_DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kitchen3">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="Kitchen3_DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kitchen4">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="Kitchen4_DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


You must know how bind your data in code behind (You can use Eval.DataBinder)

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
           DropDownList Kitchen1DropDownList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Kitchen1_DropDownList");
              ....
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check to know exactly what I need. Thank you for trying helping.

Comment: i added code, you rest just to adjust your bind on item databound

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TemplateFields` for the DropDownLists.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col1">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col2">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col3">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Here you are assigning header text for each and every column. But I want `DropDownList` for already generated header fields.

Comment: You haven't provided enough informations. What is the datasource of the grid? You can change the HeaderText programmatically if that helps. My point is, if the dropdowns are "anonymous"(look at their IDs), then you can interpret their values or events like you want.

Comment: The list of my dropdown would be 1, 2, 3, 4,5 6, 7,8,9,10 (which is a quantity value, which in turn refer to a set of values). Therefore wen I select any one value from the dropdown, For example I select value **2** in dropdownlist and I click on SAVE button,  And if my corresponding header fields is **BEDROOM1**, then in the database, for BEDROOM1 row I want to insert 2 values **abc1** and **abc2**.

Comment: My Grid should simply act as input box, then I want to read each cell and perform one single action when I hit SAVE at the bottom. I badly need this issue to be resolved. Kindly help me. I can clarify any doubts. Everytime I upload a question and some one or the other closes it, saying lack of information. Its hard to explain what I exactly need.. But I will try.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to provide more informations instead of commenting my answer. Then it would also be easier to provide a sample. You can leave a comment here that you've edited it.